# Dell Latitude 5404 Rugged - Fans not spinning or able to control with pwmcontrol

Tags: dell, fan, overheating

I have a new-ish Dell Latitude 5404 Rugged which, up until about a week ago, worked perfectly fine. I opened up the case to check out the RAM situation for upgrading, but did not make any changes to the device in that time. When I put it back together, I found that the fan was no longer spinning.

The computer will run as normal and heat up quickly. When it reaches the critical "Overheat" point, the fans will spin up for less than a second to full power, then turn back off.

Here is what I have tried:

**In BIOS:**

- Ran diagnostics, fan spins during fan checks

**In Windows:**

- Installed hwinfo, am able to setup fan curves and manually spin fan through the "sensors" menu - only when program is running

**In Ubuntu (20.04):**

- Installed psensor to check fan speeds and core temp values (Core idles around 70c, up to over 100c under load - fans only register on "max" value after the quick overheat spinup.
- Installed hwinfo, no help here
- Ran `sudo pwmconfig`, was given

```
There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.
```

HOWEVER while this utility is running, the fans spin briefly (like they do in an overheat) and then fall back to nothing.

- Installed and uninstalled i8kutils and fancontrol, neither of which worked nor gave me any error output.

Getting really frustrated with this, since it was working and all the sudden not anymore. I know the fan works since it reports RPM, and is able to be controlled via Windows and BIOS Diag, but not in Linux apparently. I have no BIOS control options available for the fan so I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. It seems that you must have done something when you opened it up. You have a hardware issue nothing to do with the Ubuntu OS. I suggest it be taken to a repair shop.

Comment: I don't usually see pwmconfig working with laptops, though it may since you can detect the fan speed.  Were you using fancontrol before or was it relying on thermald?

Comment: Prior to opening, the fans had no issues running by themselves, no software control was necessary. During opening, NO cables or connectors were moved or disconnected manually, and on re-inspection there is no unplugged components. The sensors are all reporting normal temperature levels and in hwinfo on Windows I am able to create a custom fan curve that functions as long as the program is running.